# Cannot acces my other hard disks! help!

Tags: mount, hard-drive

When I try to open my hard drive it gives this error message:

```
unable to access location

error mounting/dev/sdb2 at/media/user/b03c28983c285ba: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on/ dev/sdb2, missing codepage or helper program or other error
```

3 other hard drives get this same error message.

---

I got this by using the recommended command:

```
$ lsblk -f
NAME FSTYPE FSVER LABEL UUID                                 FSAVAIL FSUSE% MOUNTPOINTS
loop0
     squash 4.0                                                    0   100% /snap/bare/5
loop1
     squash 4.0                                                    0   100% /snap/audacity/992
loop2
     squash 4.0                                                    0   100% /snap/cherrytree/40
loop3
     squash 4.0                                                    0   100% /snap/core/12834
loop4
     squash 4.0                                                    0   100% /snap/core18/2409
loop5
     squash 4.0                                                    0   100% /snap/core20/1405
loop6
     squash 4.0                                                    0   100% /snap/firefox/1232
loop7
     squash 4.0                                                    0   100% /snap/core20/1434
loop8
     squash 4.0                                                    0   100% /snap/firefox/1300
loop9
     squash 4.0                                                    0   100% /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/161
loop10
     squash 4.0                                                    0   100% /snap/gnome-3-38-2004/99
loop11
     squash 4.0                                                    0   100% /snap/gtk2-common-themes/13
loop12
     squash 4.0                                                    0   100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1534
loop13
     squash 4.0                                                    0   100% /snap/handbrake-jz/142
loop14
     squash 4.0                                                    0   100% /snap/inkscape/10154
loop15
     squash 4.0                                                    0   100% /snap/krita/64
loop16
     squash 4.0                                                    0   100% /snap/kde-frameworks-5-core18/32
loop17
     squash 4.0                                                    0   100% /snap/snap-store/575
loop18
     squash 4.0                                                    0   100% /snap/snap-store/582
loop19
     squash 4.0                                                    0   100% /snap/snapd/15177
loop20
     squash 4.0                                                    0   100% /snap/snapd/15534
loop21
     squash 4.0                                                    0   100% /snap/snapd-desktop-integration/10
loop22
     squash 4.0                                                    0   100% /snap/vlc/2344
loop23
     squash 4.0                                                    0   100% /snap/steam/6
sda                                                                         
├─sda1
│                                                                           
├─sda2
│    vfat   FAT32       E7F9-81E7                             506.7M     1% /boot/efi
└─sda3
     ext4   1.0         d803ac9e-0507-4496-b9d9-d90a802d3b16  260.4G    36% /
sdb                                                                         
├─sdb1
│    ntfs         System Reserved
│                       3A028F1B028EDAF1                                    
├─sdb2
│    ntfs               B03C28983C285B9A                                    
└─sdb3
     ntfs               DA4C916C4C9143E3                                    
sdc                                                                         
├─sdc1
│    ntfs         System Reserved
│                       809A56959A568814                                    
└─sdc2
     ntfs               A008202D082004BE                                    
sdd                                                                         
└─sdd1
     ntfs         New Volume
                        9894699594697722
```

Comment: i am using ubuntu 22.04 lts

Comment: It may help for us to see the output of `lsblk -f`

Comment: sdd                                                                         
└─sdd1
     ntfs         New Volume
                        9894699594697722

Comment: i am getting alot of text but not sure what they mean AME FSTYPE FSVER LABEL UUID                                 FSAVAIL FSUSE% MOUNTPOINTS
loop0
     squash 4.0                                                    0   100% /snap/bare/5
loop1
     squash 4.0                                                    0   100% /snap/audacity/992
loop2
     squash 4.0                                                    0   100% /snap/core/12834
loop3
     squash 4.0                                                    0   100% /snap/cherrytree/40

Comment: i cannot post all the code here because of the 500 word limit

Comment: Unlike other forums in stack exchange you should edit the original question to include extra info rather than post again. So the output of lsblk would be better in the original question. See initial answer below.

Comment: Mount drives with Windows & turn off fast start up. https://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/unable-to-mount-windows-10-partition-it-is-in-an-unsafe-state & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation

Answer (score 2):

The output of lsblk -l suggests that sdb2 is an ntfs partition.

Firstly check ntfs-3g is installed:
`apt search ntfs-3g`

`ntfs-3g/jammy,now 1:2021.8.22-3ubuntu1 amd64 [installed,automatic] read/write NTFS driver for FUSE`

Then try this:

`mount -t ntfs  /dev/sdb2 /mnt/`

Assuming /mnt is empty or pick another empty directory